# Coloring cells that have dependents to other cells

Tags: excel, vba, performance

I have made a code that checks if the cells value has been referred in any other sheet. Simply it checks the cells dependency and colours it.
Basically what I did is it goes to the cell dependency and if the sheet name is not the one it was at the first, it colours it.

Here is the code:

```
Sub chec()

Dim r As Long, c As Long, sh As Worksheet, name As String, rg As Range, chksh As String ' r is row and c is column
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

name = "Main sheet"

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(name)
Set rg = sh.Range("A4").CurrentRegion

r = rg.Rows.Count
c = rg.Columns.Count

Dim i As Long, j As Long
i = 1
j = 1
sh.Select

Do While i < r + 1
    j = 1
    Do While j < c + 1
        sh.Cells(i, j).Select
        Selection.ShowDependents
        ActiveCell.NavigateArrow TowardPrecedent:=False, ArrowNumber:=1, _
        LinkNumber:=1
        chksh = ActiveSheet.name
        If chksh <> name Then 'there is a dependent in other sheet
        
            sh.Select
            With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
             End With
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Loop
    i = i + 1
Loop
    
ActiveSheet.ClearArrows
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

It takes too much time due to the `.select` use.

Please suggest an improved code without the use of select so that it can run in a blink of an eye.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: Would your cells always have just one dependent?

Comment: Yes, mostly only one @JvdV

Answer (score 0):

Simplified:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim sh As Worksheet, rg As Range, c As Range

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main sheet")

    Set rg = sh.Range("A4").CurrentRegion

    For Each c In rg.Cells
        c.ShowDependents
        c.NavigateArrow TowardPrecedent:=False, ArrowNumber:=1, LinkNumber:=1
        If ActiveSheet.name <> sh.name Then
            c.Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next c

    sh.ClearArrows

End Sub
```

Comment: But it takes the same amount of time. How can I make this faster?

Comment: Try setting calculation to manual in addition to screenupdating and events, but it may not get much faster.

Comment: I tried it that way itself. But it took 137 sec for a small table only. the time was the same for my code and this simplified code @Tim Williams